# How to use a definition written on locale parameters in the assumptions of the locale?

Tags: isabelle, isar

If there is some definition on the parameters of a locale which would make the assumptions of the locale easier to write and/or read and/or understand (either because the function is quite complicated so would simplify the statement of the assumptions, or its name makes the assumptions easier to read and understand), what is the best way to define that function?

As a contrived example, say we want to incorporate the function `fg` into the statement of the assumptions (not actually useful here of course):

```
locale defined_after =
  fixes f :: "'a ⇒ 'b ⇒ 'c"
    and g :: "'b ⇒ 'a"
  assumes "∀a. ∃b. f a b = f (g b) b"
      and univ: "(UNIV::'b set) = {b}"
begin

definition fg :: "'b ⇒ 'c" where
  "fg b ≡ f (g b) b"

lemma "∀b b'. fg b = fg b'" using univ the_elem_eq by (metis (full_types))

(* etc *)

end
```

One might think to use `defines`:

```
locale defined_during =
  fixes f :: "'a ⇒ 'b ⇒ 'c"
    and g :: "'b ⇒ 'a"
    and fg :: "'b ⇒ 'c" 
  defines fg_def: "fg b ≡ f (g b) b"
  assumes "∀a. ∃b. f a b = fg b"
      and univ: "(UNIV::'b set) = {b}"
begin

lemma "∀b b'. fg b = fg b'" using univ the_elem_eq by (metis (full_types))

end
```

but the locales.pdf document seems to suggest it is deprecated (but by what I'm not sure):

> The grammar is complete with the exception of the context elements `constrains` and `defines`, which are provided for backward compatibility.

Ctrl-hovering over `fg` in the lemma in the locale `defined_after` names it as `constant "local.fg"` whereas in `defined_during` it is `fixed fg\nfree variable`. It does however achieve `defined_after_def` being equal to `defined_during_def` (i.e. there are no additional parameters or assumptions in the latter), which the third option does not:

```
locale extra_defined_during =
  fixes f :: "'a ⇒ 'b ⇒ 'c"
    and g :: "'b ⇒ 'a"
    and fg :: "'b ⇒ 'c" 
  assumes fg_def: "fg b ≡ f (g b) b"
      and "∀a. ∃b. f a b = fg b"
      and univ: "(UNIV::'b set) = {b}"
begin

lemma "∀b b'. fg b = fg b'" using univ the_elem_eq by (metis (full_types))

end
```

which also has the same Ctrl-hover text for `fg` in the lemma as the `defined_during` locale does.

Maybe there's something about it in one of the PDFs on the website, or in the NEWS file, but I can't find anything obvious. isar-ref.pdf makes a comment:

> Both `assumes` and `defines` elements contribute to the locale specification. When defining an operation derived from the parameters, `definition` (§5.4) is usually more appropriate.

But I'm not sure how to use this information. Presumably it is saying that when one doesn't gain much by doing what I am asking about, one should proceed as in the locale `defined_after` (unless the quote means one can use `definition` inside a locale definition), which is not what I want. (As an aside: the first sentence of this quote would have suggested to me that `defines` is somehow equivalent to the third option which introduces an extra parameter and assumption, but that isn't the case. Maybe understanding what the possibly-subtler-than-it-appears-Isabelle-jargon "locale specification" means would explain what is causing the Ctrl-hover text to differ between the first and second option, I don't know.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specification element `defines` is indeed nothing that I would recommend to use. It goes back to a time when `definition` was not available inside a locale context and all definitions had to be done in the locale declaration itself.

Nowadays, the standard approach to your problem is to split the locale into two parts: First define a locale `l1` without the complicated assumption, but with the relevant parameters. (If you need some assumptions to justify the definition, e.g. for the termination proof of `function`, include those assumptions.) Then define your function `fg` inside `l1` as usual. Finally, define your actual locale `l` that extends `l1`. You can then use the definition of `fg` in the assumptions of `l`.

```
locale l = l1 + assumes "... fg ..."
```