# Isabelle/HOL restrict codomain

Tags: isabelle, theorem-proving

I am sorry for asking so many Isabelle questions lately. Right now I have a type problem.

I want to use a type_synonym introduced in a AFP-theory.

`type_synonym my_fun = "nat ⇒ real"`

I have a locale in my own theory where:

`fixes n :: nat`

`and f :: "my_fun"`

`and A :: "nat set"`

`defines A: "A ≡ {0..n}"`

However, in my use case the output of the function f is always a natural number in the set {0..n}. I want to impose this as a condition (or is there a better way to do it?). The only way I found was to:

`assumes "∀v. ∃ i. f v = i ∧ i ∈ A"`

since

`assumes "∀v. f v ∈ A"`

does not work.

If I let Isabelle show me the involved types it seems alright to me:

`∀v::nat. ∃i::nat. (f::nat ⇒ real) v = real i ∧ i ∈ (A::nat set)`

But of course now I cannot type something like this:

`` have "f ` {0..10} ⊆ A" ``

But I have to prove this. I understand where this problem comes from. However, I do not know how to proceed in a case like this. What is the normal way to deal with it? I would like to use my_fun as it has the same meaning as in my theory.

Thank you (again).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely at `∀v::nat. ∃i::nat. (f::nat ⇒ real) v = real i ∧ i ∈ (A::nat set)`, you will be able to see the mechanism that was used for making the implicit type conversion between `nat` and `real`: it is the abbreviation `real` (this invokes `of_nat` defined for `semiring_1` in Nat.thy) that appears in the statement of the assumption in the context of the locale.

Of course, you can use the same mechanism explicitly. For example, you can define `A::real set` as `A ≡ image real {0..n}` instead of `A::nat set` as `A ≡ {0..n}`. Then you can use `range f ⊆ A` instead of `assumes "∀v. ∃ i. f v = i ∧ i ∈ A”`. However, I doubt that there is a universally accepted correct way to do it: it depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve. Nonetheless, for the sake of the argument, your locale could look like this:

```
type_synonym my_fun = "nat ⇒ real"

locale myloc_basis =
  fixes n :: nat

abbreviation (in myloc_basis) A where "A ≡ image real {0..n}"

locale myloc = myloc_basis +
  fixes f :: "my_fun"
  assumes range: "range f ⊆ A"

lemma (in myloc) "f ` {0..10} ⊆ A"
  using range by auto
```

---

> I want to impose this as a condition (or is there a better way to do
>   it?).

The answer depends on what is known about `f`. If only a condition on the range of `f` is known, as the statement of your question seems to suggest, then, I guess, you can only state is as an assumption.

---

As a side note, to the best of my knowledge, `defines` is considered to be obsolete and it is best to avoid using it in the specifications of a locale: [stackoverflow.com/questions/56497678](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56497678).

---

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, it is much appreciated. I did not know that about defines and I am glad to learn about it.

Also the solution you suggested seems great, right now I am defining a translation fnat and then I have a lemma that  shows "f = fnat f". However, you hinted that if I have more conditions on f I would do it differently. I also assert something about the values of f, is this still the way to do it?

Comment: "the way to do it" depends on your application and will nearly always be, somewhat, opinion-based. In general, if it is possible to define `f` using the command `definition`, then it would often (but not always) be a preferable solution. As a side remark, I am curious whether it is necessary to use `real` as the codomain of `f`. Given that its domain and range are both subsets of natural numbers, would it not be more natural to use `f::nat ⇒ nat` instead of `f::nat ⇒ real`? (you can convert the output of `f` to `real` later). Also, please note that I made a minor amendment to my answer.

Comment: Thanks.
Yes it would definitly be better to use `f::nat => nat` but I want to use the typesynonym my_fun from another theory (that I did not wrote myself) since its meaning is the same. I simplified it here it is not `type_synonym my_fun = "nat ⇒ real"` but rather `type_synonym 'b my_fun = "'b ⇒ real"`